# Best way to handle null properties on a method parameter

Tags: c#

When checking a method's parameter, I throw an  `ArgumentNullException` if it's null. See the first line in the method below. But what about properties on the parameter that shouldn't be null? If I try to handle them the same way, I get a code analysis error:

> CA2208    Instantiate argument exceptions correctly   Method
>   'PriorityDeratingComponentLogic.CreateItem(IvSimulation)' passes
>   'ivSimulation.SolarPanel' as the 'paramName' argument to a
>   'ArgumentNullException' constructor. Replace this argument with one of
>   the method's parameter names. Note that the provided parameter name
>   should have the exact casing as declared on the method.

```
public DeratingComponentBase CreateItem(IvSimulation ivSimulation)
{
    if (ivSimulation == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("ivSimulation"); }
    if (ivSimulation.SolarPanel == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("ivSimulation.SolarPanel"); }
    if (ivSimulation.GlobalEquipment == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("ivSimulation.GlobalEquipment"); }

    // ... method body here
}
```

Is the CA error something I should suppress, or is there a generally-accepted way to better handle this? Perhaps the issue is upstream and we shouldn't even have to check for those properties being null at this point?

Comment: Yeah, that code analysis error message looks stupid. This looks perfectly fine to me. Stuff like this is why I've never used code analysis software before...

Comment: `IvSimulation` should prevent construction of invalid values, so it should validate `SolarPanel` and `GlobalEquipment`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Throwing an `ArgumentNullException` is intended to indicate that the argument itself is `null`. However, when one of argument components is `null`, but the argument itself isn't, the proper exception is `ArgumentException` with the name of the argument as parameter:

```
if (ivSimulation.GlobalEquipment == null) {
    throw new ArgumentException("GlobalEquipment cannot be null", "ivSimulation");
 }
```

This provides the information about the error in the message, while specifying `ivSimulation` as the parameter name.

**Note:** I assume that you have no choice of validating `GlobalEquipment` in the constructor of `IvSimulation`, because throwing `ArgumentNullException` would be a perfectly valid choice in that constructor.

Comment: You could do something like this:
`throw new ArgumentException("Global Equipment cannot be null", "ivSimulation");` to give more information.

Comment: @EricHotinger That's a better choice indeed, thank you very much!

Comment: I'd prefer a **NullReferenceException** ("The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.") instead of an ArgumentException ("The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.") because the argument itself is valid, but it's null.

Answer (score 1):

It can be argued that a null property on a non-null parameter variable isn't really a null argument, so the `ArgumentNullException` is not actually appropriate in this case. (Clearly, others may disagree, which is fine.) This feels to me like a qualitatively different situation. The argument isn't missing, but it is in an invalid state. I think I would use an `InvalidOperationException` for cases like this, where an object is in an invalid state.